# awk, mawk, nawk, gawk... WHAT?

Tags: unix, awk

I've just started learning awk and I'm a little confused about all those versions around. Is there any "version" which is found on all Unix-like systems? Like, you know, plain vi? Does the standard awk support the -F option?

Comment: See also [The differences between gawk and mawk (column width)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289110/the-differences-between-gawk-and-mawk-column-width)

Answer (score 53):

**awk** - the most common and will be found on most Unix-like systems, oldest version and inferior to newer ones.

**mawk** - fast AWK implementation which it's code base is based on a byte-code interpreter.

**nawk** - while the AWK language was being developed the authors released a new version (hence the **n** - **n**ew awk) to avoid confusion. Think of it like the Python 3.0 of AWK.

**gawk** - abbreviated from GNU awk. The only version in which the developers attempted to add i18n support. Allowed users to write their own C shared libraries to extend it with their own "plug-ins". This version is the standard implementation for Linux, original AWK was written for Unix v7.

There are other versions like jawk (java implementation), bwk (Brian W. Kernighan's implementation) and so on.

Comment: The original awk isn't present on any Unix-like system I have available. Often, `/usr/bin/awk` will run nawk, or gawk, or BusyBox awk (similar in behavior to gawk).

Comment: As of late 2012, Ubuntu/Debian systems install mawk by default. The command line `file /etc/alternatives/awk` returns `symbolic link to /usr/bin/mawk`

Comment: does MAWK have all GAWK functionalities such as true multi-dimensional arrays ?

Comment: I know this is late @WYSIWYG but mawk does have a few quirks, mainly with regexp's though you are best to install gawk if you want a portable implementation IMO.

Comment: @JordonBedwell Yep.. There are: regex repetitions are not possible in mawk. It also doesn't support multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @dubiousjim Ubuntu has original-awk in the universe repository.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Also some functions like `strtonum` are missing.

Comment: My Raspbian Stretch installation has `awk`, `gawk`, `igawk`, `mawk` and `nawk`. available, but `awk`, `nawk` and `igawk` are either symlinks to, or wrappers of, `gawk`. Interestingly, on the more up-to-date Raspbian Buster I installed a few days ago, `(i)gawk` has vanished and all the symlinks now point to `mawk`. Quirky it may, be but it seems `mawk` is the future, at least on certain distros.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use `awk`. It is defined by POSIX and therefore has to exist on all POSIX-conformant systems.

The `-F` parameter is [mandated by that](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/awk.html) as well.

Comment: ...but take care to check with the standard to tell what you can use to insure compatibility with other version. Don't, for instance, use `gensub()`, test with `awk` --> `gawk`, and think you're good to go...

Comment: @dmckee, you can use `gawk --posix` to make gawk work according to POSIX standard. It also checks your script follows the standard. You could use `awk --posix '' 2>/dev/null` in Ubuntu no matter, if gawk, mawk or original-awk is used as awk, but the posix-option is only recognized by gawk. --posix has to be the last option for original-awk. You could use `awk -W posix ''` with gawk and mawk.

Comment: @dmckee, oh `mawk --posix ''` fails, if you use mawk 1.3.3, but succeeds with error message, if you use mawk 1.3.4

Answer (score 2):

`awk` will be on just about every *NIX based system, but the exact specifics of what it supports will shift slightly as it's entirely possible it will simply be symlinked to a different version akin to how `/bin/sh` is often linked to a specific shell, often `bash` or one of its derivatives. (For the record, I also know alot of machines where `vi` is symlinked to `vim` as well.)

Comment: Needn't always be symlinked; sometimes it's hard-linked.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia AWK page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is a good starter reference for beginning to understand AWK.
The [Field Separator](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Command-Line-Field-Separator.html) option '`-F`' is supported in all variants of AWK -- afaik.